# There is SQL query which show percentage in output. But i cannot understand the output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query like it will show the percentage in the report output but i cannot understand the query in this part how this percentage is calculating. Why decimal(3,0) and CAST(round[%,0]) there are using in query. Please help on this query.

```
@beta=14.4
@current=14.5

(Select cast(round([%],0) as decimal(3,0))
 from (Select count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() '%', (case when a.OperatingSystem like concat(@Beta,'%') or a.OperatingSystem like concat(@Current,'%') then 'Current' else 'Not Current'  end) as [Status]
```

Comment: It is dangerous to discuss a fragment of a script. So why don't you ask the original coder, the person that gave you this assignment, your seniors, or anyone else with expertise in your organization? Why the casting and rounding? Because that was needed by the consumer of this query fragment.

Comment: Wow that's confusing: they have a column called `%`

Comment: @Charlieface, yes it is confusing but `%` looks to be a column alias rather than a column name.